# Execute last statement after thread finished

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a problem. I have the following Code. In the second line I start a thread which works fine but my problem is that the `CloseQueueClient` closes before the thread gets started. Is it possible to run the `CloseQueueClient(queueClient);` after the thread is finished? I tried it with wait then it works but the whole Gui thread gets blocked and the Gui doesn't update.

```
QueueClient queueClient = CreateQueueClient(queueName);
Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ReceiveMessagesFromQueue(queueClient));
CloseQueueClient(queueClient);
```

Comment: Why don't you put the creation and closing of your class into the thread?

Comment: If I may put a sidenote here: Technically you're not starting a *thread* (you'd use the `Thread` class for that), but a *task*, which can be seen as another abstraction for concurrency. It's up to the TPL on which thread your task is going to be executed. Typically, it might either start a new one, or grab a thread out of a thread pool, and the underlying thread might be re-used for different tasks instead of being destroyed. Not that this difference is relevant to this question, but I think it's still worth a coffee break read or so.

Comment: Hy, I have a few problems with the update. Is the task class the problem? I opened a new thread because it is a other question. Maybe someone has an idea?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22513483/update-observablecollection-in-list-box-in-thread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is probably a *continuation*:

```
QueueClient queueClient = CreateQueueClient(queueName);
Task task = Task.Factory
    .StartNew(() => ReceiveMessagesFromQueue(queueClient))
    .ContinueWith(t => CloseQueueClient(queueClient));
```

The code above executes the continuation on any thread. Should you need to use the UI thread, use an explicit `TaskScheduler` using [`FromCurrentSynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.fromcurrentsynchronizationcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
task.ContinueWith(t => CloseQueueClient(queueClient),
    TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Comment: @user2644964 Glad we helped. If either of the answers solved your problem, could you mark the solution you used as an accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it this way:

```
QueueClient queueClient = CreateQueueClient(queueName);
Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
            {
                ReceiveMessagesFromQueue(queueClient);
                CloseQueueClient(queueClient);
            });
```